# UV issue when importing model to Substance Painter

Tags: texturing, uv, export, .fbx

so I just started using Substance Painter and when I import my model as an FBX from Blender the UV's appear fine in the UV window in painter but as soon as I apply any texture it is mapped strangely.

[image: UV's in blender]
[image: UV mapping]

I only have one material on the object, I applied the modifiers and transforms on export, changed up and forward axis and also tried exporting as an OBJ instead of FBX.

[image: Model after importing into Painter with the correct UV's]

Here I just added a random grunge texture to the base colour of a fill layer. No matter what I change I always get this same mapping on the model, even switching to triplaner mapping gives a similar result.

[image: Stretched UV seams]

[image: UV layout view]

Here is what the generated curvature map looks like from substance.

[image: Curvature map]

Here I applied the curvature map as a mask to a fill layer.

[image: Curve map mask]

Comment: May be you have multiple UVMaps.

Comment: Hard to see whether your UVs are nice based on the first screenshot. However, if this is all fine in Blender, your issue most likely is that you forgot to *generate the mesh maps* in painter: https://helpx.adobe.com/substance-3d-painter/using/baking.html

Comment: @Emir I just have a principled BSDF as the only shader. How would I add a picture as a comment?

Comment: @FFeller I only have one uv map on the mesh.

Comment: @brockmann I added a picture of the uv mapping in the post, let me know if thats sufficient for painter. Also I did generate the mesh maps and when I viewed them they looked perfect, however as soon as I applied them they gave this strange mapping.

Answer (score 0):

My sculpt was 9 million polygons, so it seems Substance didnt know what to do with it. Exported out at a lower resolution on the multires modifier and then baked the high poly back on seemed to work. Not sure what the poly limit is in Substance.

Comment: It looks like it's 10M triangles (which is very likely to be less than 9M polygons since blender supports Quads and N-Gons) https://substance3d.adobe.com/documentation/spdoc/mesh-and-uv-setup-168198996.html